# Quasi Linear PDE solution using characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics, cauchy-problem

The question in the textbook reads:

Consider the PDE:

$$\sin(t)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + x \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{x}{t}$$

subject to $u = x$ on $t = 4$.

My characteristics can't be solved in terms of elementary functions and I'm stuck with:

$$\frac{dx}{\sin(t)} = \frac{dt}{x} = \frac{du}{x/t}$$

---

Edited: PDE corrected.

Comment: There are a couple typos I think: in the PDE is it $\sin(x)$ or $\sin(t)$ (because on the bottom line you have $\sin(t)$ but above you have $\sin(x)$)? Also, in the PDE, you have two $t$ derivatives of $u$; presumably one is supposed to be $x$.

Comment: That's the form it was given as. $\sin(t)u_x + xu_t = x/t$

Comment: Ok, but above in the first equation you have $\sin(x)$ written instead of $\sin(t)$, and you have $\partial u/\partial t$ twice, rather than $\partial u /\partial t$ and $\partial u/\partial x$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dx}{\sin(t)} = \frac{dt}{x} = \frac{du}{x/t}\qquad\text{is correct}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{\sin(t)} = \frac{dt}{x}$ :
$$\frac{x^2}{2}+\cos(t)=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $ \frac{dt}{x} = \frac{du}{x/t}$ :
$$u-\ln|t|=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE from the implicit equation $c_2=F(c_1)$ is :
$$u=\ln|t|+F\left(\frac{x^2}{2}+\cos(t)\right)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function.

Condition : $u(x,4)=x$
$$\ln|4|+F\left(\frac{x^2}{2}+\cos(4)\right)=x$$
Let $X=\frac{x^2}{2}+\cos(4)\quad\implies\quad x=\pm\sqrt{2X-2\cos(4)}$
$$F(X)=-\ln(4)\pm\sqrt{2X-2\cos(4)}$$
Now the function $F(X)$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution where $X=\frac{x^2}{2}+\cos(t)$

$F\left(\frac{x^2}{2}+\cos(t)\right)=-\ln(4)\pm\sqrt{2\left(\frac{x^2}{2}+\cos(t)\right)-2\cos(4)}$
$$u=\ln|t|-\ln(4)\pm\sqrt{2\left(\frac{x^2}{2}+\cos(t)\right)-2\cos(4)}$$
$$u=\ln\left|\frac{t}{4}\right| \pm\sqrt{x^2+2\cos(t)-2\cos(4)}$$
The sign of the square root has to be chosen so that the condition $u(x,4)=x$ be satisfied at $t=4$. That is $+$ if the argument is $>0$ or $-$ if the argument is $<0$.